# How do I monitor my total received network traffic from time x to time y?

Tags: networking, system-monitor

I assume that the System Monitor app tracks the total MiBs received since startup. I would like to track the total MiBs received since an arbitrary point of time after startup.

I often use a Samsung 4G wireless hotspot, and it would be useful to monitor how fast I'm using up my alotted monthly data I'm using during a particular session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [vnstat](http://humdi.net/vnstat/), it is available in the repositories. You can set up what network interface you want to monitor and check the amount of traffic you have used so far.